# char * not returned correctly from overloaded operator or memory managment issue

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I try to read a file decompress it and parse it to a tree in C++. Everything works fine with one excaption: For some reason I can construct a char[] string and use a pointer on it to output it with the help of cout inside a befriended overloaded <<-operator, but can't use the pointer returned by the operator to cout the string. I was thinking it might have to do with visibility of the string-memory, but that makes no sense to me since with "new" allocated memory should be visible to everyone since its on the heap of the program and not somekind of object or class heap. This all sounds rather confusing, let me show you a striped down version of the source and I'm pretty sure everything becomes clear (probably some really stupid mistake on my end... but I try since two days and don't find the mistake):

main:

```
#include "dekompstream.h"

#include <iostream>

int main(void) {
    char *testString;
    DekompStream ds(nullptr, 0);

    std::cout << "TEST" << std::endl;
    testString << ds;
    std::cout << "Outside operator: " << testString << std::endl; // Fails misarably. Some weird randome memory-slice looking output

    //delete [] testString;

    return 0;   
}
```

dekompstream.cpp:

```
#include "dekompstream.h"

DekompStream::DekompStream(uint8_t *kompDaten, unsigned int anzahlBytes) {
}

DekompStream::~DekompStream() {
}

uint8_t *DekompStream::dekompremieren() {
    char *test = new char[4];

    test[0] = 'A';
    test[1] = 'B';
    test[2] = 'C';
    test[3] = '\0';

    return (uint8_t *)test;
}

char *operator<<(char *zeichenkette, DekompStream &dekompStream) {
    zeichenkette = (char *)dekompStream.dekompremieren();

    std::cout << "Inside operator: " << zeichenkette << std::endl; // Works fine

    return zeichenkette;
}
```

dekompstream.h:

```
#ifndef DEKOMPSTREAM_H
#define DEKOMPSTREAM_H

#include <cstdint>
#include <iostream>

class DekompStream {
    public:
        DekompStream(uint8_t *kompDaten, unsigned int anzahlBytes);
        ~DekompStream(void);

        friend char *operator<<(char *zeichenkette, DekompStream &dekompStream);
    private:
        uint8_t *dekompremieren();
};

#endif
```

Thanks in advance :-)

Comment: `testString << ds;` looks odd. Usually the stream is on the left and the `<<` is in the other direction. Something like `ds >> testString;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`testString << ds` doesn't do what you think it does.

If we take a look at the code for `operator<<`:

```
char *operator<<(char *zeichenkette, DekompStream &dekompStream) {
    zeichenkette = (char *)dekompStream.dekompremieren();

    return zeichenkette;
}
```

The function reassigns the `char*` argument to a new value, then returns the new value. Fine. OK. But how does the compiler use this?

When we write:

```
testString << ds;
```

The compiler turns it into:

```
operator<<(testString, ds);
```

See the error?

You returned a new value, but because the operator overload was turned into a function call, the allocated pointer was lost. In addition, because the `char*` argument was simply reassigned, the original pointer value wasn't changed, meaning you got whatever was on the stack previously.

If we look at the declarations for the STL functions for iostream, we'll see the way to fix it:

```
ostream& operator<< (ostream& os, const char* s);
```

Notice the first parameter is passed by reference - this ensures any modifications to the stream made by the function persist in the calling context.

Simply change your function definition to:

```
char *operator<<(char *&zeichenkette, DekompStream &dekompStream){
...
}
```

and the issue will disappear.

Comment: I see. Thanks for the explanation.